# How to build a large image viewer

Tags: android

I need to build a component to view large images.

I cannot put the ImageView in a ScrollView because I will need to be handle other touch events on the image.

The ideal would be to build a "viewer"

- with an horizontal handle
- and a vertical handle

that enable to move where the picture is centered so that I can scroll the image using the handles without touching the picture itself.

I would like to achieve something like in the following picture, I have researched but I was not able to find any Android API or other component/library that I could use.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I can think of is use two custom scrollbars for the horizontal and vertical scroll. In an onChange() function you can change the crop area on the master image and display the cropped image. Depedning on how it is done you can get a slide effect going for the image.

Comment: thanks Brianjs, the point is that I need the scrolling to happen without touching the image, but only the handles, because I need to intercept other touch events on the image

Comment: If you placed a layout within a scrollview you can still handle other click/touch events within. I have used images with clickable parts inside scrollviews in the past. Such as you are doing here. if you want the separate scroll-able bars you just have to change the x/y positioning of the scrollview inside the onSeek/valueChanged listeners of the seekbars, that way you don't have to touch it.

Comment: Id be more than happy to scrounge up some examples